# Date Conversion - Spark SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column which is a date in this format;

```
Fri Mar 08 14:12:32 +0000 2013
```

And I would like to see that data in this format;

```
2013-03-08 14:12:32.000000
```

I've tried some functions for conversion such as to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, string timezone), however I got null results.

I need to use it with spark.sql("") like;

```
spark.sql("select TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('08/26/2016', 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS TIMESTAMP)) AS newdate ").show(20, False)
```

Sorry for my english, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You kind of already answered this, you just needed to head to [the java date format options.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
spark.createDataFrame(List((1,"Fri Mar 08 14:12:32 +0000 2013")))
res0.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
spark.sql("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(_2, 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS') FROM test").collect
```

The only thing is that once it's in a time_stamp format then you use FROM_UNIXTIME to get it into the string you want.

Comment: Thank you Justin for your answer. However, I still don't know how to convert it to this (2013-03-08 14:12:32.000000) format

Comment: Updated my answer. I guess you are missing FROM_UNIXTIME? Otherwise it just takes a review of the format table